# how can i work with 16 digit integer type?

Tags: c, types

problem: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/486/A

input:

```
1000000000000000
```

output:

```
-1
```

answer:

```
500000000000000
```

Checker log:

```
wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '500000000000000', found: '-1'
```

code:

```
int main() {
    int a, b = 0, c = 0, d, i;

    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (i = 2 ; i <= a ; i++) {
         if (i % 2 == 0) {
             c = c + i;
         }
         if (i % 2 != 0) {
             b = b + i;
         }
     }
     d = c - b;
     d = d - 1;

     printf("%d", d);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int64_t` or `long long`. A small hint: can you transform the equation to be more timeefficent?

Comment: no my code is not working with long long..can u arrange the code for me pls ??

Comment: you can combine the first and second number ( -1 + 2 = 1) and the third with the fourth ( -3 + 4 = 1) and so on. How much 1s do you get? Now think at the end, what's left if the last number is even and what's left if the last number is odd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest value an `int` can hold is 2,147,483,647.  Change the variables to `unsigned long long`, which can hold a maximum of over 18,446,744,000,000,000,000.  (You'll need to use `%llu` to read in/out `unsigned long long` variables)

Also, always validate inputs, this would have hinted at the issue.

```
if(scanf("%d", &a) < 1) { //if we read less than one
    printf("FAILED TO READ INPUT");
    return 1;
}
```

Finally, you're iterating from 2 to 1000000000000000, which is going to take a LONG time regardless of what's inside the loop.  You'll need to use a faster algorithm in order to complete in the one second deadline.

Comment: And the `scanf()` /`printf()` specifier for `long long int`/`unsigned long long int` is `"%lld"`/`"%llu"`.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks, I overlooked that

Comment: but what about  %I64d or %I64u ??

Comment: @Esterified: Those were Microsoft extensions from before `%lld` was invented.  `%lld` was the standard that replaced them.  Those old ones still work, but `%lld` is more portable.